# QUERY function places blank rows from bottom of original spreadsheet at the top of the new sheet

Tags: google-sheets

It seems pretty straight-forward. I query the columns and ask it to sort the results in asc or desc order by a single column. The problem is that I cannot add any additional rows to my original spreadsheet or it places blank rows at the top of my Query sheet. Here is the formula I am using:

```
=QUERY('Jose 2013 Master'!B1:V500; "select B,O,E,S,T,U,V,G ORDER BY G asc", 1)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you need to filter those out, as in "where G<>'' "

Comment: I believe grouping by the contents of a column will allow you to filter out the additional rows, as the previous poster says.